# Changing a Tkinter GUI variable

Tags: python, tkinter

I need help changing a variable in Tkinter GUI.
I have a basic script but have an error with it: a missing 1 required positional argument

Here is the script:

```
from tkinter import *

num_picked = ""

root = Tk()
Label(root, text='What is your favourite number?').pack()

def b1_s(num_picked):
    print ("So your favourite number is 1")
    num_picked = 1
def b2_s(num_picked):
    print ("So your favourite number is 2")
    num_picked = 2
def b3_s(num_picked):
    print ("So your favourite number is 3")
    num_picked = 3

Label(root, text= num_picked).pack()

b1 = Button(root, text="1", command=b1_s)
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(root, text="2", command=b2_s)
b2.pack()

b3 = Button(root, text="3", command=b3_s)
b3.pack()

mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```

But when I click the buttons on the run, the idle python shell comes up with the error.

Comment: what part of the problem do you need help with? Clearly your functions take parameters, and clearly the button isn't passing them. Are you wanting to know how to pass parameters, or to write your functions so they don't require parameters..?

Comment: Hi, what error are you getting?  Can you add the error message to the post?

Comment: A Button's command does not pass an argument, your three functions all require one argument so when they are called they miss one required argument, just like the error message tells you. Just remove `num_picked` from your function definitions, there's no reason for them to be there anyway.

Comment: Please note that changing the `num picked` variable will not automatically update your Label, you will have to do this using `widget.configure(text=...)` or using a StringVar or IntVar as textvariable for the label.

Answer (score 0):

This common problem stems from the difference between a function and the value returned by a function. A `tkinter` widget's `command` parameter expects to be passed a function, as you are doing in your code. However, the function you want to work with needs an argument. If you were to simply call that function with an argument within the `command` parameter:

```
b1 = Button(root, text="1", command=b1_s(1))
```

the `Button` would fail, because the `command` would then be `None`, the return value of the `b1_s(1)` function, and you can't call `None` because it's not a function. So, what we do to fix that is to use something called a `lambda` function, which is a way of defining an inline function. That gives us something like this:

```
b1 = Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: b1_s(1))
```

This gives us the output we expect. However, we can do more than this. Since we are now able to pass arguments to a function, we don't even need separate functions in this case.

There was also an issue with the way you were workign with `Label`s. First, you should create a `Label` and `pack()` it in the same statement, or it makes it impossible to save that widget to a reference - which you weren't doing anyway, making it hard to work with those `Label`s. Save the `Label` in one statement and `pack()` it in another. Next, if you want a function to be able to work with a reference that was assigned outside of the function, you need to pass that reference in as an argument.

This leads to the following code, which, when the user presses a button, prints that button's number to the console and displays the number in the GUI window.

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

def fav_num(label, num_picked):
    print ("So your favourite number is", str(num_picked))
    label.config(text=str(num_picked))

title_label = Label(root, text='What is your favourite number?')
title_label.pack()

mylabel = Label(root, text='')
mylabel.pack()

b1 = Button(root, text="1", command=lambda: fav_num(mylabel, 1))
b1.pack()

b2 = Button(root, text="2", command=lambda: fav_num(mylabel, 2))
b2.pack()

b3 = Button(root, text="3", command=lambda: fav_num(mylabel, 3))
b3.pack()

mainloop()

root.mainloop()
```